# C# XAML Assemblies from remote location

Tags: c#, xaml, assemblies

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253505/xaml-xmlnslocal-c/6253607#6253607) question.  It may seem that the issue lies with my project files/assemblies being stored on a network location, and due to the fact that assemblies run from a remote location are loaded partially trusted.

I have looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252.aspx) link, which states to put the following in the config file:

```
      loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"
```

I have done this in the app.config file, but nothing has happened.  One thing that made me think, was that in the config file, intellisense was working fine, but there was no element called loadFromRemoteSources in the list.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks.